# A bug in matlab quad function?

Tags: matlab

There seems to be a bug in Matlab `quad` function for evaluating integrals using quadrature formula. Running

```
quad(@(x) (2/sqrt(2*pi))*(x.^2).*exp(-x.^2/2), 0, 10)
```

give back `1.0000` which is the correct answer but increasing the upper limit say to 100, that is

```
quad(@(x) (2/sqrt(2*pi))*(x.^2).*exp(-x.^2/2), 0, 100)
```

gives back `3.4715e-8`. This seems to be the case also for `quadl`. The `integral` command, however, seems to work fine. Is this a known issue or am I missing something?

Comment: Interesting. Increasing lower bound only to .01 gives back 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading `quad`'s [documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/quad.html), it looks like it might be a good idea to use `quadgk` instead. In this case it gives the correct results with the integration interval (0,100):

```
>> quadgk(@(x) (2/sqrt(2*pi))*(x.^2).*exp(-x.^2/2), 0, 100)

ans =

    1.0000
```

Comment: Thanks, that might be right choice then. Though it is still strange that the other `quad` functions are so unstable.

Comment: Agree. And it's not really clear if `quadgk` is always the best choice, or when to select each variant

Comment: @passerby51, et al.: Quadrature is just like numerical integration - there are many methods and one needs to use a method appropriate for the function at hand and/or use the appropriate settings. Exponential, logarithmic, and periodic functions often need special care. For example, in double precision, this function evaluates to zero for `x` greater than 38.7. `quad` can actually be used if the tolerance option is set sufficiently small, e.g. `1e-12`. But `quadgk` (or `integral` in newer versions) is almost always a better first choice.

Answer (score 1):

Running both expressions with `quad` and `quadl` on [octave](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php) resulted to 1. Something might be wrong with the machine.

Comment: It might have to do with MATLAB version, implementation, etc. It might have been fixed in the more recent version. (I have found it in R2012a on a Linux machine.)